# Pagination not working in DevExtreme DataGrid with Custom Store that lacks skip and take options for paginated API requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, devextreme

I'm working with DevExtreme and have implemented a custom store for paginating a DataGrid. However, the `loadOptions` object in my custom store doesn't contain `skip` and `take` properties, causing them to appear as `undefined`. As a result, I'm unable to achieve proper pagination when requesting data from the API in a paginated manner.

Here's the relevant part of my script.js:

```
// Configuring API URL
const apiUrl = 'https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds';

// Function to load data using Custom Store
const loadDataSource = (loadOptions) => {
    const { skip, take } = loadOptions;

    console.log({ skip, take });

    const params = {
        page: Math.floor(skip / take) + 1,
        limit: take,
    };

    console.log(params);

    return fetch(`${apiUrl}?page=${params.page}&limit=${params.limit}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => ({
            data: result,
            totalCount: result.length,
        }));
};

// Creating a Custom Store for pagination and data loading
const customStore = new DevExpress.data.CustomStore({
    load: loadDataSource,
});

const grid = $("#data-grid").dxDataGrid({
    dataSource: customStore, // Using Custom Store as the data source
    columns: ["id", "Product Name"], 
    paging: {
        pageSize: 10 // Setting the number of items per page
    }
}).dxDataGrid('instance');
```

Since the `skip` and `take` properties are missing from the `loadOptions` object in my custom store implementation, the pagination is not functioning as expected. I want to request data from the API in a paginated manner, fetching portions of data at a time, instead of all at once. How can I properly implement pagination using a custom store for the DevExtreme DataGrid in this scenario? Any suggestions or insights on achieving paginated API requests for the DataGrid would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hello! have you resolved your issue? can you share the solution for pagination in devextreme? thanks!